# Batch file output missing files to a textfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, file-io, cmd

I am trying to make a batch file to look for file names based on a list I have in a text file (one file name per line without an extension ) 
The batch file needs to search in a folder+subfolders and output the files it DIDN'T FIND to a text file (Missing.txt)`

```
echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (Filelist.txt) DO echo %%i>InList.txt
(
IF NOT EXIST %%i (echo %%i>Missing.txt) 
)
```

ok so now InList.txt have all the file names from Filelist.txt regardless if they exist or not 
and Missing.txt has %i in the file

ok so this is the code i used to solve my problem
    `@echo off
    for /f  "tokens=*" %%i in (Filelist.txt) DO (
    IF EXIST %%i.* (echo %%i>>InList.txt) ELSE echo %%i>>Missing.txt
    )`

my filenames inside Filelist.txt had no extensions so i added .* after the %%i in the IF statement but if your filelist has extensions you can use the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood the format of a for loop. You also need to use `>>` to append to a text file, instead of `>` which will write over the file. Going off of your original logic, where `InList.txt` will contain **all** files, and `Missing.txt` will only contain missing files:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (Filelist.txt) DO (
    echo %%i>>InList.txt
    IF NOT EXIST %%i (echo %%i>>Missing.txt) 
)
```

But if `InList.txt` should only contain files that ***do*** exist:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (Filelist.txt) DO (
    IF EXIST %%i (echo %%i>>InList.txt) ELSE echo %%i>>Missing.txt
)
```

Comment: it works now but it will only find files with extensions(filename.txt) is it possible to look for files without extensions (filename)?

Comment: It is possible, so long as the name isn't a duplicate (i.e. `file.txt` and `file.exe` without the extension are both just `file`).

Comment: so what do i need to add? at the moment i have two files in my directory test1.txt and test2.txt after i added two names to the file list : **test1** **test2.txt** the **test1** shows as missing the **test2.txt** is in the list

Comment: depends: are all entries in Filelist.txt without extension, or do some have an extension, while others don't?